# How to get external IP informations via command line?

Tags: networking, ip

I'm trying to get informations about an IP which was used to send me a form message which could be malicious. Is there a way to get some informations about it from shell/terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for ISP and region:

```
whois 1.1.1.1
```

Do a reverse DNS

```
dig -x 1.1.1.1
```

Do a ANY DNS query on the reverse DNS:

```
dig ANY one.one.one.one.
```

Search for CNAME name aliases:

```
dig CNAME one.one.one.one.
```

Use a `traceroute`:

```
mtr 1.1.1.1
```

Check also tools online like https://network-tools.com/

Tools like `nmap` is to use at your own risk to detect remote OS. This is considered as *intrusive*.

You can also search for the terms `osint+ip address` on your favorite search engine.